# How to set charset utf-8 for jquery i18n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding, localization

I tried to localize my web app with jquery.i18n but I have some problems with umlauts.

In my jsp page I set the following:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="script.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>

<label data-i18n="specification"> Specification / Ausprägung </label>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            //onload
            $.i18n().load({
                'de' : '/js/i18n/de.json'
            }).done(
                    function() {
                        $.i18n().locale = 'de';

                        $('body').i18n();
                    });});
```

And the de.json:

```
{
    "@metadata": {
        "authors": [
            "xyz"
        ],
        "last-updated": "2018-06-06",
        "locale": "de"
    },
    "specification" : "Ausprägung"
}
```

but all I get is `Auspr�gung`. Beside the umlauts, jquery.i18n works fine. How can I make it use utf-8 encoding?

Comment: UTF-8 should be the default for any library in 2018. Is your code/app using UTF-8 as encoding?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you so much, that was what I missed. I set eclipse encoding to utf-8 and saw the same wrong sign in my json file. Please add this as an answer so I can except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 should be the default for any library nowadays and [jquery.i18n](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n), while not bleeding edge, appears to be a serioius project. Being precise, the JavaScript interpreter will automatically parse source code encoded as UTF-8 and convert strings to its internal encoding. I bet the library works with any encoding out of the box as long as it's properly declared (e.g. by sending a correct `Content-Type` header).

The `�` character in `Auspr�gung` is a typical symptom of single-byte encoding misinterpreted as UTF-8. Your editor is probably configured to save files as ANSI (Windows-1252 or whatever) but the stack is configured to assume UTF-8.